# Set Pod Restart Limit

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod

Can we ***set Pod Restart Limit*** like Docker swarm in Kubernetes?

> Docker swarm restart_policy:

```
    condition: any
    delay: 60s
    max_attempts: 2
    window: 60s
```

or any other way because k8s kind Deployment doesn't support Restart Policy `never` or `onfailure`

My Deployment.yaml:-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xyz
  labels:
    app: xyz
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xyz
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xyz
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: xyz
        image: x.y.z
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: x
      restartPolicy: Never
```

***Error***
`is invalid: spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Never": supported values: "Always"`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is **impossible**. In [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#pod-template) its mentioned that it allows only `Always`.

> Only a `.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy` equal to `Always` is allowed, which is the default if not specified.

Same situation with `DaemonSet` and `StatefulSet`.

It is related to `Deployment` [concept](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/deployment) that all pods must be in `Running` state, pod cannot fail or be unresponsive.

> Deployments represent a set of multiple, identical Pods with no unique identities. A Deployment runs multiple replicas of your application and automatically replaces any instances that fail or become unresponsive. In this way, Deployments help ensure that one or more instances of your application are available to serve user requests. Deployments are managed by the Kubernetes Deployment controller.

As default, `Deployment` automatically creates [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) which also taking care of pods status.

> A ReplicaSet is defined with fields, including a selector that specifies how to identify Pods it can acquire, a number of replicas indicating how many Pods it should be maintaining, and a pod template specifying the data of new Pods it should create to meet the number of replicas criteria. A ReplicaSet then fulfills its purpose by creating and deleting Pods as needed to reach the desired number. When a ReplicaSet needs to create new Pods, it uses its Pod template.

Only `pod` and `job` kind is able to use `restartPolicy` with `Never` and `onFailure` values.

Answer (score -1):

run `kubectl run --help | grep restart`

you will see that there is a restartpolicy setting as follows

```
 --restart='Always': The restart policy for this Pod.  
Legal values [Always, OnFailure, Never].  
If set to 'Always' a deployment is created, if set to 'OnFailure' a job is created, 
if set to 'Never', a regular pod is created. 
For the latter two --replicas must be 1.  Default 'Always', for CronJobs `Never`.
```

Note: There is a [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65797) for a new option called `maxRetries` but it is currently stale and unavailable.

Comment: May I know the link from where you have got "maxRetries" option?

Comment: There is no `maxRetries` field.
`kubectl explain pod --recursive | grep -i maxRetries`

Comment: This is a wrong answer and should be down voted, there is no maxRetries setting available. Though, there should be one...

Comment: see this issue and the comments: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65797 

Seems the initial PR has gone stale though

Comment: Documentation is wrong. Only `Always` is supported. Do not attempt that...